# How to make action in pynput keyboard listener with timer module

Tags: python, python-3.x, pynput

I am making rc car with rasberry pi 4 and python, but for left and right i want to increase angle of servo motor with time so basically i want to make this as psudo:

```
normalangle = 90
if left button pressed:
   if timepassed < 25:
      car.turnleft(normalangle + timepassed)
```

and this is my code

```
import carcontrol
from SensorClass import distanceSensor
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO          
import time
from pynput.keyboard import Key,Listener

sensor1 = distanceSensor(6,5)
carcontrol.setpstart(30)
carcontrol.servo(90)

def on_press(key):
    distance = sensor1.startCalculate()
    if key == Key.up:
        if(distance > 20):
            carcontrol.forward()
        elif (distance < 30 and distance > 20):
            print("something is coming")
        else :
            carcontrol.stop()
            print("you cannot move forward")
    if key == Key.left:
        carcontrol.servo(160)
    if key == Key.down:
        carcontrol.reverse()
    if key == Key.right:
        carcontrol.servo(20)

def on_release(key):
    if key == Key.up:
        carcontrol.stop()
    if key == Key.left:
        carcontrol.servo(90)
    if key == Key.down:
        carcontrol.stop()
    if key == Key.right:
        carcontrol.servo(90)

# Collect events until released
with Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Also i want to check every second distance sensor. i added as code in on_press section. but its just working when i first pressed. if i hold it its not checking. so how can i check every second ?

Comment: Do you mean that when press some buttons or wait some time it will do the check work?

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA for example if i start left button it angle will be start increasing by time

Comment: After you press the left button at the first time,the angle will increase even you didn't press the button anymore.Right?

Comment: Nope it will incerse every second when i pressed button after i release my angle will return to 90 which is starting point